# Difference between Injectables and Observables?

Tags: angular

I have been working upon my new **Angular2** app and is confused between **Injectables** and **Observables**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two aren't related in any way. You can use `Observables` in `Injectables` like anywhere else, but that's about it.

An `Observable` is similar what is known as `Stream` in other languages.
An `Observable` can be subscribed to and when it emits events, subscriber get notified. `Observable` is a bit like `Promise` but for a possible series of values instead just one value.

`Injecable` is a class that can be instantiated and injected by Angulars DI.
(dependency injection).
When a class has a decorator like

```
@Injectable() 
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(private http:Http) {}
}
```

and some other class (for example an Angular2 component) like

```
@Component({...}
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private someClass:SomeClass) {}
}
```

that is instantiated by Angulars DI, DI inspects the constructor parameters and looks up injectables that match the constructor parameter declaration, creates a new instance (in this case of `SomeClass`), but because `SomeClass` also has a constructor parameter, DI first has to look up or create a new instance of `Http` to be able to pass it to `SomeClass`.

An `Injectable` therefore is a class that can be instantiated by DI: